# 2D quadrature of interpolated data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have an array `Q` representing the result of a simulation defined on a 2D grid whose Cartesian grid points are available on two arrays `X` and `Y` (these are all 2D arrays of same shape). I also have a function `Qexact` which defines the exact solution of the simulation. This is a function of two parameters `x` and `y` which returns the value of the exact solution at the given position. The function can work on either scalars and numpy arrays.

Since I'm testing simulation with varying grid spacing, I use a common grid `X_common` and `Y_common` and I bilinearly interpolate my solutions `Q` on this grid. I do so using the function [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html). I subtract from here the exact solution, I take the absolute value of the result and I get the absolute error defined on this common Cartesian grid.

I would like to integrate this result in my domain now. I plan to use [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) for this. The problem is that the values which should be returned by my integrated function are computed using an interpolation.

In other words, my function for the integration could be implemented as follows:

```
def func(y, x):
    '''Returns the absolute error at the position (x, y)'''

    # Interpolate the global array `Q` at position (x, y)
    # The list `points` is a global variable holding the
    # values of the grid on which `Q` is defined
    xy = np.array([[x, y]])
    Qval = scipy.interpolation.interpn(points, Q, xy)

    # Compute reference value of Q at the requested position
    # By using the exact solution
    Qref = Qexact(x, y)

    # Return absolute error
    # (Remark: I could have to extract the only value
    # out of the ndarray)
    return abs(Qref - Qval)
```

The issue with this is that I would have to call the interpolation function once for each point used by `scipy.integration.dblquad`. I suspect this could be very expensive as opposed to call it just once with a big array `xy` to get all the needed values all at once.

The question is: **Will the prototyped method shown above be much slower than the ideal method where all the points needed by the interpolation are computed at once?**

The related question is: What is the most efficient way to implement this integration?

Comment: Any reason you are integrating over the error instead of over the square or absolute value of the error?

Comment: No, in facts you are correct, I'm integrating the squared error because I'm computing the L2 norm, but I decided to simplify the question, which is already quite complex I think. But I guess I could be interested in the L1 norm and so just integrate the absolute value of the error itself, as I did in the question..